# php and mysqli prepared update is updating all rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm finding that a prepared update using mysqli is updating all the rows in my table instead of the one referenced in the WHERE clause. I'm stumped as for the reason this is happening. I used simplified code below to run as a test, and it still happens. I'm using PHP 5.3.18 and the Client API library version 5.0.96.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

$query = "UPDATE test SET first_name = ? WHERE last_name = ?";
if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
  die("Unable to prepare<br />");
}

$first = 'test';
$second = 'something';

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $first, $second);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
  die("Could not execute<br />");
}

echo "done";
```

The query executes, but the first_name is updated for all rows in the table. Yes, there is a last_name with "something." No, the three other test rows do not have the last_name = something.
Is this something wrong with the library? My PHP config? Perhaps not enough sleep? What?

Oh... in addition... if I use a query like
    "UPDATE test SET first_name = ? WHERE id = ?"
and update the params to use an id, it works. It only updates the single row. So why can't I use the last_name column in the WHERE clause?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query it works good on my machine and yes it will update all the  columns whose second name is 'something'

Comment: is it really 'test', 'something' you are using to test?

Comment: @hek2mgl - Yes, the table name is "test" and the last_name column is varchar with the value "something." I created the table just to run simple tests, as the issue was occurring with other tables. As I said, not all last_name row values are "something". I have a local machine running XAMPP and the query works.

Comment: Testing today, I added another varchar after last_name called `asp` and tested it inside the where clause. When the value was a string, it updated all rows. When I changed the value in `asp` to numbers (still varchar) it worked and only updated one row. This is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I had the server techs update my server to MySql 5.5 and the issue is now fixed. I'm guessing it had something to do with the library or MySql install.

Comment: Strange behaviour. Will make a test myself soon. Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I'm trying to prevent having to upgrade the entire server to PHP 5.5